# Why does Jim have no back story?

Tags: passengers

In Passengers, Chris Pratt's character "Jim", apparently has no backstory to his character. When being "interviewed" by Aurora, he even avoids answering the questions properly. On the other hand, we learn why Aurora is on the trip, and even get a glimpse into her childhood.

Is there any narrative or other reason why Jim doesn't have a backstory?

**EDIT:** This won't affect the question much, but I'd just like to clarify the motive behind it. When I watched the movie, I found plenty of openings for Jim to reveal something personal about himself, his life, his hopes and dreams - but he never does, apart from one or two facts.

I feel this may have something to do with the "old" and "new" personas of Jim and Aurora. Aurora's motives are based on her past whereas Jim's are based on his future.

Comment: There's a little backstory in this deleted scene https://youtu.be/Ntf00HkGktE?t=2m33s

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We are told why Jim is on the ship - he tells Aurora at one point that he's fed up of living on Earth because "people don't fix things there, they just buy a new one."  On Homestead II, Jim can actually build and repair things - literally build the future with his own hands.  As an engineer by trade, this is something that appeals to him.

It's true we aren't told anything about his family, but I think it's safe to assume that's because there's not much to tell.  Even in Aurora's case, the most we're told about her family is that her father was a famous writer.  Nothing about the rest of her family.

Comment: I've added a bit more to my question, outlining *why* I asked it. I think your answer meets that a bit, if you wanted to perhaps clarify your point a bit more?

Comment: Jim also had no intents of returning home, which very much hints that there isn't much worth returning to, for him at least.

Answer (score -4):

Passengers is original screenplay, characters background not very well designed.

That is why Jim has no back story.